# How do i fix this issue with django start project?

Tags: python, django

After I installed django i wrote the start project command to verify django is working or not.
i.e,

```sh
django-admin startproject mysite
cd mysite
python manage.py runserver
```

After that I got an IP address(http://127.0.0.1:8000/)
but when i link to this http://127.0.0.1:8000/, it is showing **unable to connect**. what should i do now?

Comment: check the logs of the server you just ran

Comment: what do you see in your console?

Comment: Are you run it on your computer or inside another virtual machine or Docker container?

Comment: 1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlfuK.png  2]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve1me.png     these are the thing i did!

Comment: @PriyaranjanDash, are you pressing `CTRL-BREAK` just after running the server?

Comment: No i didn't press, i just pressed cd to show  django version

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry this is not a big issue!
As per your comment mentioned above, Run the `python manage.py runserver` then go to new instance of powershell and do other stuff what you want to try. 
Let that runserver window isolated.

Comment: just press ctrl+break. Its simple as that.